# Is it possible to use pipe to create a comunication stream between 2 processes without using stderr, stdin or stdout?

Tags: c++, pipe

As in the question. Can i connect 2 processes (parent and child) sending informations through pipe() but without using stdout, stdin or stderr? Can i create a new stream or buffer to use?

EDIT:

My child process starts a new program through execl() that needs to communicate with the first program through pipes without using stdin and stdout.

The code i'm using at the moment to comminicate through those streams is the following:

```
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

pid_t
popen2(const char *command, int *infp, int *outfp)
{
int p_stdin[2], p_stdout[2];
pid_t pid;

if (pipe(p_stdin) != 0 || pipe(p_stdout) != 0)
    return -1;

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0)
    return pid;
else if (pid == 0)
{
    close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
    dup2(p_stdin[READ], READ);
    close(p_stdout[READ]);
    dup2(p_stdout[WRITE], 2);

    execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command, NULL);
    perror("execl");
    exit(1);
}

if (infp == NULL)
    close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
else
{       
    *infp = p_stdin[WRITE];
}

if (outfp == NULL)
    close(p_stdout[READ]);
else
{        
    *outfp = p_stdout[READ];
}

return pid;
}
```

I'm currently communicating reading from stdin and writing to stdout in my child process. What if i wanted to read and write from a different buffer i create to prevent possible data corruption due to prints and mistakes? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a tool for interprocess communication to do... interprocess communication? That's like asking if a hammer can be used to drive nails into wood.

Comment: You are right however i might have missed something on my question. Let's say the forked pid starts a new programm with execl(). Normally i would communicate from the father process to the child process (the one executed via execl) and viceversa using stdin and stdout since both have a reference to it. However if i don't want to use those but use something like the solution provided below by @ani1998ket how can i pass to the second program a reference to the buffers i'm using instead of stdin and stdout?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You're asking how to gain access to a pipe that one process created from a different process not created from the source.

Comment: I tried to edit my question to be more specific. Sorry for the bad question before i'm a bit burnt out from the work day.

Answer (score 0):

Well pipes are used for the exact purpose you are mentioning.

Here is an example from Beej's guide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfds[2];
    char buf[30];

    pipe(pfds);

    if (!fork()) {
        printf(" CHILD: writing to the pipe\n");
        write(pfds[1], "test", 5);
        printf(" CHILD: exiting\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("PARENT: reading from pipe\n");
        read(pfds[0], buf, 5);
        printf("PARENT: read \"%s\"\n", buf);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For more info : https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/pipes.html#pipesclean